# How do I get to the next web page on this site?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get to the next page of a JavaScript dynamic site. http://msds.walmartstores.com/ The element I've been trying to activate to get to the next page is:

```
<a href="#" class="next" data-action="next">›</a>
```

On this website:
http://msds.walmartstores.com/

Which can be found within this:

```
<div class="pagination" id="pagination" style="">
    <a href="#" class="first" data-action="first">«</a>
    <a href="#" class="previous" data-action="previous">‹</a>
    <input type="text">
    <a href="#" class="next" data-action="next">›</a>
    <a href="#" class="last" data-action="last">»</a>
</div>
```

***I am able to get the all of the JavaScript elements (PDF's) I want to scrape on this page. How do I get to the next page?***

**Problems I've run into / attempts:**

## 1

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("next").click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 56, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 50, in main
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 77, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 494, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element i
s not clickable at point (251, 2173)
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cf
d9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

## 2

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("next").submit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 56, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 50, in main
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 88, in submit
    self._execute(Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 494, in _execute return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", 
line 236, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\sitepackages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, 
in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Element was not in a form, so could not submit.
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),
platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Here is my code to open the webpage:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import os

url = "http://msds.walmartstores.com/"
    myfile = open("PDFLinks.txt", "w")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I came up with:

Since everything I've tried gave me errors, and attempting to click on the element gave me a "unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (251, 2173)" I came up with a work around.

At the bottom of the site there is a place for me to insert a number for a page, I used that to move to the next page and had a counter in my program.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


while is_next_there(driver):

    go_through_page(driver, myfile, page)

    #Gets the next page, and waits for load
    el = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='pagination' and @id='pagination']")))
    el.find_element_by_xpath(".//input").clear()
    el.find_element_by_xpath(".//input").send_keys(page)
    el.find_element_by_xpath(".//input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    page += 1
```

With this solution I am able to successfully get to the next page

Answer (score 0):

Try with the xpath:

```
el= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagination' and @id='pagination']")
el.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='next']").click()
```

**EDIT**

I tried with this html (based from yours) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>

<div class="pagination" id="pagination" style="">
    <a href="#" class="first" data-action="first">«</a>
    <a href="#" class="previous" data-action="previous">‹</a>
    <input type="text">
    <a href="#" class="next" data-action="next" onclick="myFunction()">›</a>
    <a href="#" class="last" data-action="last">»</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and it works. Probably you have to do more info about your html.

**EDIT2**

I took a look to your interested webpage. From your code is not clear what do you want to do, and in your question is not explained the steps to do.

I noticed that if I click in the "Submit" button, a list of .pdf will appear. And in this case, there is the element in which you are interested. 
So, I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver.get("http://msds.walmartstores.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("submitUPC").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
el= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='pagination' and @id='pagination']")))
el.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='next']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it unfortunately didn't fix my problem :(

Comment: I just posted the link to the website in the question, http://msds.walmartstores.com/

Comment: Could there be something wrong with my selenium package? I'll have to look more into it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I use C#, but this should be close. I've had more luck with CSS Selectors for hard to reach elements. 
I don't see an iframe or anything weird, so this should work. This uses a combination of CSS Selector and JavaScript to locate and click your next button. You may need to do a bit of adapting from C# to Python, but it should solve your problem.

```
By next = By.CssSelector("#pagination > a.next");
        IWebElement nextButton = driver.FindElement(next);

IJavaScriptExecutor clickNextButton = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        clickNextButton.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", nextButton);
```

Comment: FYI, I'm aware that this can be shortened, but I think this makes a better example, because it shows all the steps.